# Pause and play VLC in background

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is it possible to pause and play a video in the VLC media player using any keyboard shortcut (w/o using any mouse) when I am working in another window? For example, say I am reading a PDF while a video is running in the VLC media player. Is it possible to pause and play the video w/o minimizing the PDF reader?

I tried to get a solution by searching in the web but couldn't find one.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open VLC, go to Tools -> Preferences.
- Click on Hotkeys
- Find Play/Pause action. Click on the its row at the Global column. Set a key (see image below). <kbd>Space</kbd> is set as the global key.
- Restart VLC. Whenever you press the key you set, VLC will play/pause.

**Note:** I set <kbd>Space</kbd> as the global key as an example. Please choose, select the key carefully as it might interfere with other apps.

[image: VLC Preferences - Hotkeys]